# How to upgrade Nautilus on 14.04 LTS to the version shipped with 16.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, updates, nautilus, lts

Is it possible to upgrade Nautilus on `14.04 LTS` to the version that ships with `16.04 LTS`? If so, how?

Comment: its been over 2 years and I'm still looking for an answer.....I'm hoping that this comment will 'bump' the question in the `Active` tab, because I'd like an answer but it isn't worth a bounty of 50 rep to me